# XAMPP can't start Apache in mac

Tags: apache, xampp

I tried to use xampp to start apache server in mac, however it didn't work, and the log showed the following information:
[image]

I tried to change the port of apache from 80 to 81 or other ports, but it still can't start.

Could anyone please help? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sudo apachectl stop, I use this command to shut down the pre-installed apache on mac, and then it works. Yeah!