# XAMPP can't start Apache on Mac

Tags: macos, apache, xampp

manager-osx flicks from "Starting…" back to "Stopped" with no error, and when I run `sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/ctlscript.sh start apache` on the command line, I get back:

```
Syntax OK
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd started
```

I've tried port swapping and running `sudo apachectl stop` to stop the built in server (as described at [XAMPP can't start Apache in mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37149964/xampp-cant-start-apache-in-mac)), but no luck. Open port scan doesn't show any live Apache servers on my machine. I've reinstalled XAMPP (multiple different versions), but nothing.

Running macOS Catalina 10.15.1.

Update: I've also tried using MAMP, and it can't start Apache either.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp start
```

run this command to Start XAMPP on MacOS Catalina.

Comment: Just tried that on a new install, got ```httpd: Syntax error on line 522 of /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 10 of /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf: Cannot load modules/libphp7.so into server: dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/modules/libphp7.so, 10): Symbol not found: _iconv\n  Referenced from: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/libintl.8.dylib\n  Expected in: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/libiconv.2.dylib\n in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/libintl.8.dylib```

Comment: check this for the error - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51324558/1117368